# Control recursion on nested lists / strings

Tags: python, generator

Assume I have the following input:

```
items = [1, 2, [3, 4], (5, 6), 'ciao', range(3), (i for i in range(3, 6))]
```

and I want to perform some recursive operation on `items`.

For the sake of simplicity, let's say I want to *flatten* items (but could be anything else), one way of doing this would be:

```
def flatten(items, shallow=(str, bytes, bytearray)):
    for item in items:
        if isinstance(item, shallow):
            yield item
        else:
            try:
                yield from flatten(item)
            except TypeError:
                yield item
```

this would produce:

```
print(list(flatten(items)))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 'ciao', 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Now how could I modify `flatten()` so that I could produce the following (for arbitrary nesting levels)?

```
print(list(flatten(items)))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 'c', 'i', 'a', 'o', 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add a length check next to the shallow check:

```
if isinstance(item, shallow) and len(item) == 1:
```

Comment: Actually, I want to use the `shallow` parameter to prevent descending through for any type. So I would still be able to, say, not descend into `tuple()` but still be able to control this for `str`. Also, relying on a list of *special* types for which not descend if length is `1` seems a bit brittle. Would you be able to provide an approach that does not rely on checking for `str`, `bytes` and `bytearray`?

Comment: Fair enough, I have asked another question with the additional requirement https://stackoverflow.com/q/59903905/5218354

Comment: you can simply create a subclass that behaves like `str` and type-checking will not work....