# Control recursion on nested lists / strings (without checking for the type)

Tags: python, recursion, generator

Assume I have the following input:

```
items = [1, 2, [3, 4], (5, 6), 'ciao', range(3), (i for i in range(3, 6))]
```

and I want to perform some recursive operation on `items`.

For the sake of simplicity, let's say I want to *flatten* items (but could be anything else), one way of doing this would be:

```
def flatten(items, max_depth=-1, shallow=(str, bytes, bytearray)):
    for item in items:
        if shallow and isinstance(item, shallow) or max_depth == 0:
            yield item
        else:
            try:
                for subitem in flatten(item, max_depth - 1, shallow):
                    yield subitem
            except TypeError:
                yield item
```

this would produce:

```
print(list(flatten(items)))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 'ciao', 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Now how could I modify `flatten()` so that I could produce the following (for arbitrary nesting levels)?

```
print(list(flatten(items, shallow=None)))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 'c', 'i', 'a', 'o', 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

---

Other inputs to be supported:

```
items = [['best', 'func'], 'ever']
print(list(flatten(items, shallow=None)))
# ['b', 'e', 's', 't', 'f', 'u', 'n', 'c', 'e', 'v', 'e', 'r']
```

---

Note: I am looking for an approach that does not rely on explicitly checking for `str`, `bytes` or `bytearray` as this is quite brittle, should it appear another type which has the property that iterating through it yields the item itself.

This is related to the following: [Control recursion on nested lists / strings](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59903362/5218354)

Comment: This is why not having a distinct `char` type is a pain.

Comment: Actually, that's not the only problem. Consider how you would flatten `a`, where `a = [1]; a.append(a)`.

Comment: In general, you don't know whether iterating an item yields the item itself. The only way to find out is actually iterating it.

Comment: Why declare bytes and bytearray as shallow? They don't have the problem that str does, do they?

Comment: @HeapOverflow the `shallow` parameter is to specify for which types the recursion should not happen if it is possible to iterate through.

Comment: Oh, I guess I misunderstood. I thought `shallow` was just an attempt to avoid infinite recursion. But now I think you do want it as a feature of the function, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change

```
        if shallow and isinstance(item, shallow) or max_depth == 0:
```

to

```
        if shallow and isinstance(item, shallow) or max_depth == 0 or item == items:
```

then it gets all three examples right.